# targetSDKVersion, minimumSDKVersion, and compileSDKVersion for specific device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I'm programming for one specific device and I'm having trouble understanding how I should be setting minsdkversion, compilesdkversion, and targetsdkversion. I want to get a compiler error when I'm using a library that doesn't exist for API level 25. Here's what I gatherered. Minsdkversion prevents calling API that doesn't exist for API version. Compilesdkversion should always be the latest version. Targetsdkversion is what the app was tested against (don't understand what this means).

minsdkversion-25
compilesdkversion-28 (needed for AndroidX)
targetSDKversion-25

Comment: Can you share the error logcat

Comment: "a library that doesn't exist for API level 25" What do you mean by this? And what SDK is installed on the device?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm programming for a device that has an OS with Android 7.1 (API Level 25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Version settings

Among those version settings, only minSdkVersion takes effect to detect API level error. If you'd like to know details of the version settings, see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element).

#### How to let build system report API level error

For ***release builds***, place "lintOptions" in app/build.gradle and mark "NewApi" as "fatal". Then lintVitalRelease gradle task reports error during compilation.

```
android {

    lintOptions {
        fatal "NewApi"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30

        :
    }
    :
}
```

#### Checking API level manually

In ***debug builds***, the lintOptions above doesn't have any effects because the lint is not included in debug build tasks (there is no lintVitalDebug gradle task). So rather, after coding, [run "code inspection" manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections)  to detect all the NewApi problems in your code. If incompatible API uses found, you'll see "calling new methods on older version" error in the inspection result.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Is there a way to get a compile error instead of just a warning? With Lint, I can only see the report and what went wrong.

Comment: I think lintVitalRelease does stop compiling with NewApi error. Doesn't it? The lintVitalRelease is minified version of lint for detecting fatal errors only, which doesn't care warning level problems. If it does not work as such, some other options may be required in your environment. For available LintOptions, please see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.